# Creating 4 responsive boxes that cover the whole page

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

My goal is:
[These 4 boxes.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpBgL.jpg.)
I want to have those 4 boxes maintain coverage of the whole page regardless of the size of your viewport(?). So at a desktop view they are all wide rectangles and as you get smaller they will eventually turn into squares and at a mobile view it's probably vertical rectangles. Is this possible with just HTML and CSS?

I've tried other examples but nothing seems to answer what I'm looking for. I've tried using vw and percentages for the boxes but even if I get the width correct the height will only be relative to the width and not the size of the whole page.

The task seem relatively simple but I can't find an answer anywhere for the life of me. Please help! Thanks.

Comment: It seems I was trying to over complicate things when I was trying to use float by myself. Now, I have to learn more about flexboxes as another way to solve it. Thank you everyone who posted. They all worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using flexbox:  https://jsfiddle.net/wosmqs2v/

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box {
  height: 50vh;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  min-width: 300px;
}

.box1 {  background: red;}
.box2 {  background: blue;}
.box3 {  background: green;}
.box4 {  background: orange;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box box1">1</div>
  <div class="box box2">2</div>
  <div class="box box3">3</div>
  <div class="box box4">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: We made almost the same. Flexbox FTW!

Comment: Hells yea, get with it float people, why not use a table while your back there in the past :)

Answer (score 1):

Best regards!

p.s. Floats are from the past, Flexbox FTW.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
 width:90%;
 max-width: 1200px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.boxes {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 max-height: 100vh;
}

.box {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 50%;
 height: 50vh;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}

.green { background: green; }
.blue { background: blue; }
.pink {background: pink; }
.yellow { background: yellow; }
```

```html
<div class="container boxes">
 <div class="box green">1</div>
 <div class="box blue">2</div>
 <div class="box pink">3</div>
 <div class="box yellow">4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you have to set the `width` and `height` of each `div` to `50%` and to `100%` for the `body` and `float: left` all the `div`s. Demo:

```css
.quarter:first-child {
  background: red;
}
.quarter:nth-child(2) {
  background: blue;
}
.quarter:nth-child(3) {
  background: green;
}
.quarter:nth-child(4) {
  background: purple;
}

.quarter {
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
 } 
 
 html, body {
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
  }
 }
```

```html
<div class="quarter"></div>
<div class="quarter"></div>
<div class="quarter"></div>
<div class="quarter"></div>
```

Comment: If this helped you, please mark the answer as accepted by clicking the check mark next to it. See: [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more information

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
div {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}
div:nth-of-type(1) {
  background-color: red;
}
div:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: green;
}
div:nth-of-type(3) {
  background-color: orange;
}
div:nth-of-type(4) {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: ow! at full screen those colors make my eyes wig out. +1